# Route 53 : www traffic redirecting to naked domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

These are the steps I followed:

1. got a new domain name from AWS domain registry. Lets say example.com
2. Create a certificate with the help of ACM for example.com
3. My Cloudfront distribution(lets say dXXXXXXXXXX.cloudfront.net) points to a S3 folder (contains some images)
4. Cloudfront url with aws provided distribution name works fine (lets say: https://dXXXXXXXXXX.cloudfront.net/1.jpeg)
5. Added example.com as alternate domain in that distribution definition and imported the certificate of example.com in CloudFront
6. Added one A and one AAA entry in the route53 where source is: example.com and target is:dXXXXXXXXXX.cloudfront.net
   7.Added an alias type 'A' entry where source is [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) and target is example.com
   8.Now when I try to use url:  https://www.example.com/1.jpeg , it is showing can't connect to the server of [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) where as if I use https://example.com/1.jpeg , it shows the picture.

Please help me here.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `CNAME` instead of `Alias A`.

Try this instead

```
www.example.com  CNAME  example.com
example.com      A      Alias <_id>.cloudFront.com
```